# What problems (other than crypto) can quantum computing solve?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

So my (limited) understanding of quantum computing lends its self very well to breaking public-private crypto; by being able to factor products of large primes.

However in some press releases (google quantum supremacy, october 2019) I saw vague press copy, around how it will advance chemistry and medicine etc.

Now by all mean we may not have discovered a use for it yet, and we most likely will. (I remember a story of some politician scathingly querying the utility of this new electricity thing. Haha!)

So my question is:

**Other than crypto, what practical applications, in the near future, are there for quantum computing?**

Comment: Although Peter Shor is sometimes active on physics.SE, cs.SE is probably a better place to ask this. If you want to move it, I think you can just delete this one and post a copy on the other site.

Comment: Also see https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

[The quantum algorithm zoo](https://quantumalgorithmzoo.org/) gives a lot of examples, ranging from the theoretically interesting to the possibly practically useful.

Some examples of algorithms that may (if quantum computers get good and the algorithms don't have too much overhead) be useful: factoring numbers, decoding some error correcting codes, constraint satisfaction, searching unordered lists in $O(\sqrt{N})$ time, gradient descent (plus a lot of other machine learning algorithms), quantum simulation (of chemical dynamics, solid state, field theories...), and simulated annealing optimization.